# SonarQube issue: Remove duplicates in this character class

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I have implemented the regex expression to remove all the special characters with empty strings and remove space(if any), which is working fine in my code but sonarQUbe is complaining as this is non-compliant solution, Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue

```
String c = "test10101010test%79%% %%% $$$  \t \n $$$#$@^$%~`***c  33";
    Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[\\W\\s+]");
    Matcher match= pt.matcher(c);
    while(match.find())
    {
        c=c.replaceAll("\\"+match.group(), "").toLowerCase();
    }
     System.out.println(c);
```

I am getting error at `"[\\W\\s+]"`. Getting below error
Remove duplicates in this character class.

Can anyone suggest how to fix this issue?

Comment: All special chars (punctuation + whitespace) is `Pattern.compile("[\\p{P}\\p{S}\\p{Z}]")`. Maybe you just wanted all non-alphanumeric? `Pattern.compile("\\P{Alnum}")`?

Comment: But this pattern does not replace the  \n  and  \t   characters from a string which I hv in my validation and working with previous regex expression

Comment: They do, just check the answer below with several solutions listed. Check them only in code, not at any online regex testers.

Answer (score 3):

Your regex is a character class, `[...]`. It matches `\W` (chars other than letters, digits or connector punctuation (underscore in ASCII mode), `\s` (a whitespace) and a `+` char. The error you get is related to the fact that both `+` and whitespace chars can already be matched with `\W`.

So your pattern is basically `\W`. Note it does not match underscores that are punctuation chars. If you want to remove all chars other than alphanumeric chars use `[\W_]` or `\P{Alnum}` pattern.

More, you usually do not need to check for a match before replacing, the following should be enough:

```java
c=c.replaceAll("\\W+", "").toLowerCase();
// or
c=c.replaceAll("[\\W_]+", "").toLowerCase();
// or
c=c.replaceAll("\\P{Alnum}+", "").toLowerCase();
```

**Note** this warning will appear in cases where you specified a case insensitive flag `/i` and use character classes to match letters in either case like `[zZ]` (`/[zZ]/i`). This is clear you need to replace the character class with a single letter, `z` or `Z` here.

Answer (score -1):

As Wiktor Stribiżew mentioned in the comment section the solution to fix the SonarQube issue is

```
String c = "test10101010test%79%% %%% $$$  \t \n $$$#$@^$%~`***c  33";
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\P{Alnum}");
Matcher match= pt.matcher(c);
while(match.find())
{
    c=c.replaceAll("\\"+match.group(), "").toLowerCase();
}
 System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: The problem is that `\s` is a non-word char, `\W`. Also the `+` in a `[.]` does not make sense. But I think the entire code needs some clearance.